# Bending guitar strings

Tags: note-bending

I am having a big time struggle trying to bend guitar strings. The problem is that my fingertips are hard from playing acoustic guitar so whenever i try to bend a string in my electric guitar i end up flicking another string accidently due to my hard fingertips.

Comment: Use an emery board (nail file) to remove a little bit of your callous.  Go gently at first until you know from experience how much and how hard to file.  That's the main thing I want to tell you.  However, as a minor additional note -- dishwashing softens callouses.